# What is the difference between Maxwells demon and a refrigerator?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon)

> the demon's behavior causes one chamber to warm up as the other cools

Isn't that the same what a refrigerator does? But nobody says a refrigerator is a challenge to the Second Law of Thermodynamics, because everybody agrees that a refrigerator needs energy from outside to work. Why is there such a big fuzz then about Maxwells demon? What is the difference between Maxwells demon and a refrigerator?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Maxwell's Demon, is that it violates the second law of thermodynamics. The demon creates a net decrease in entropy, by sorting the particles.

As you say, a refrigerator does the same thing: Heating one system (The outside environment), while cooling another (The inside of the refrigerator). In cooling the interior, it will decrease the entropy of the interior system. However, in order to not violate the second law of thermodynamics, it must increase the entropy of the outside environment by at least as much as it decreases the interior entropy, such that there is a net increase in entropy.

In practice, this extra increase in entropy comes from the fact that the refrigerator must do some work in order to move the heat from the cold to the hot system. This extra work means that there is an excess of energy dumped into the outside system, compared to the energy removed from the inside system and this is where the extra increase in entropy comes from.

Comment: But why does everybody believe, that one can sort the particles in Maxwells demon without using external energy?

Comment: Well you can't. That is kind of the point with Maxwell's Demon, that it violates thermodynamics and hence cannot be possible, at least not without thermodynamics being wrong. Why you can't do that is still a topic of discussion. One argument is that the demon would have to use a very sophisticated system of getting information about the particles, and that this system alone would be enough to give a net increase in entropy. You should check out the [Wikipedia article] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon)